# Python script that reads csv files

Tags: python-3.x

script that reads **CSV** files and gets headers and filter by specific column, I have tried researching on it but nothing of quality I have managed to get.

Please any help will be deeply appreciated

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Answer (score 0):

There's a standard `csv` library included with Python.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

It will automatically create a dictionary of arrays where the first row in the CSV determines the keys in the dict.

Answer (score 0):

You can also follow [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for the same.